# Proof for Mean value theorem for integrals

Tags: calculus, mean-value-theorem

I have the proof in my book for the mean value theorem for integrals $$\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx = f(c)\int_a^b g(x) dx$$

However, I don't understand the proof especially at the beginning where the proof starts with $$F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) g(t) dt - \frac{A}{B} \int_a^x g(t) dt$$

$$A = \int_a^b f(x)g(x) dx$$
$$B = \int_a^b g(x) dx$$

Where this formula come from?

Comment: That is almost impossible to understand: is $\;F(x)\;$ being defined by that equality, or it is defined *before* and then they tell us that that equality exists...?

Comment: The proof begins right with that. Page 561 from the textbook mathematics for physicist by Lea.

Comment: @epselonzero Where is an online copy of the page? It would be easier to see the proof then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula did not come from any where, it is a definition of a new function $F(x)$ that will help during the proof. To avoid confusion i will denote this function as $H(x)$.

First of all The definition of the function $H(x)$ is
$$
H(x)=\intop_a^xf(t)g(t)dt-\frac{A}{B}\intop_a^xg(t)dt
$$
Where $A=\intop_a^bf(t)g(t)dt$ and $B=\intop_a^bg(t)dt$.

Because $g(x)>0$ and is continuous, then $\intop_a^bg(x)dx>0$, so $H(x)$ is well defined.

Assuming that $g(x),f(x)$ are continuous functions, from the [Fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) it follows that $H(x)$ is a differentiable function. Notice that
$$
\begin{align}
H(a)=&\intop_a^af(x)g(x)dx-\frac{A}{B}\intop_a^ag(x)dx=0\\
H(b)=&\intop_a^bf(x)g(x)dx-\frac{\intop_a^bf(x)g(x)dx}{\intop_a^bg(x)dx}\intop_a^bg(x)dx=\\
=&\intop_a^bf(x)g(x)dx-\intop_a^bf(x)g(x)dx=0
\end{align}
$$
So by [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem) there exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that $H'(c)=0$. From the [Fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) the derivative is
$$
0=H'(c)=f(c)g(c)-\frac{A}{B}g(c)
$$
And with a little arithmetic and because $g(c)\neq0$ we will get
$$
A=f(c)\cdot B\,\Rightarrow\,\intop_a^bf(x)g(x)dx=f(c)\intop_a^bg(x)dx
$$

Comment: I understand a bit more, but I still don't see how to get F(a) from the fundamental theorem of calculus which is $\int_a^b f(t) dt = F(a) -F(b)$ where F'(t) = f(t).

Comment: Hi @epselonzero. that is not the fundamental theorem of claclulus, that's called the Newton-Leibniz formula. Please check the links i've provided.

Comment: I found this here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements

I try to reproduce the the function F(x) from that.

Comment: @epselonzero Now i understand you question. Well, for every function $\intop_a^af(x)dx=0$, if you want to prove it for every function then by the definition of riemann integral the riemann sum is zero for every partition. if you are allowing us to assume that $f(x)$ has an anti derivative than by Newton-Leibniz formula if $F'(x)=f(x)$ then $\intop_a^af(x)dx=F(a)-F(a)=0$

Comment: I'm not clear, sorry. I'm trying to find how to get $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) g(t) dt - \frac{A}{B} \int_a^x g(t) dt$ since you typed $F(a) = ...$ and $F(b) = ...$ I thought I had to use $\int_a^b f(t) dt = F(a) -F(b)$.

Comment: I think there is a confusion about the notation's of the book. $F(x)$ is not the anti derivative of $f(x)$, it is just a function defined by $F(x)=\intop_a^xf(t)g(t)dt-\frac{A}{B}\intop_a^xg(t)dt$. from this definition we can conclude that $F(a)=F(b)=0$

Comment: Why is $H(a)=\intop_a^af(x)g(x)dx-\frac{A}{B}\intop_a^ag(x)dx=0 $ if $A = \intop_a^bf(t)g(t)dt$ and $B = \intop_a^bg(t)dt$

Comment: @epselonzero it is because $\intop_a^af(t)g(t)dt=\intop_a^ag(t)dt=0$, as for all integrable function $j(x)$ it holds $\intop_a^aj(t)dt=0$